# How do you configure JOGL with java in 2024 lol

Tags: java, windows, graphics, helper, jogl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
at jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.awt.WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfigurationImpl(WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:171)
at com.jogamp.nativewindow.GraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:424)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1560)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:611)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4846)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4846)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4846)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:791)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:495)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1053)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1728)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1675)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1036)
at com.mulope.graphicsintro.Code.(Code.java:26)
at com.mulope.graphicsintro.Code.main(Code.java:36)

i have tried different IDE's but nothing seems to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s is not a proper question for Stackoverflow. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).